# How to find a file in unix with the filename * in a given directory?

Tags: unix

Recently I have been asked a question in interview which was tricker

Need to find a file in Unix with the filename *(extensions doesn't matter here) in the given directory

I answered that file name can not start with * in any filesystems.
He said it's possible

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With demonstrating ***`touch`***-***`ls`*** steps (`*` char should be enclosed in quotes or escaped  with `\` to prevent shell *globbing*):

```
$ touch '*'
$ ls -l '*'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 osboxes osboxes 7 Nov  3 19:04 *
```

Answer (score 2):

The only [illegal characters in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230299/26300) are NULs (`\0`) and slashes (`/`). Anything else is valid.

`*` is not a special character in file names, but it is to the shell. You can escape it to prevent the shell from treating it as a glob.

```
ls '*'
ls "*"
ls \*
```

You can mix this with a glob by leaving the glob unescaped.

```
ls '*'.*
ls "*".*
ls \*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the * with a \, so for instance you can use:

```
ls \*.*
```

This will search for a file with the name "*" in the current directory without taking in consideration the extension.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hvn8.png)

Answer (score 0):

* is a special character to the shell that's interpreting your commands, it's not special in file names. In order to use '*' in a file name, you need to escape it in the shell command.

If the file may be in a subdirectory, you can find it using find:

```
$ mkdir -p given/directory
$ touch given/directory/\*
$ find . -name '\*' -print
./given/directory/*
$ rm given/directory/\*
$ find . -name '\*' -print
$
```